# Watching Netflix on 0.4 Loki

Tags: epiphany, chromium

What about Netflix application on Elementary OS? I tried it with Epiphany and Chromium and it does not work,  I'm redirected to https://help.netflix.com/en/node/23742

Any solution? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Netflix's Linux support is limited to Chrome and Firefox. To watch Netflix, you could:

- [Install Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html)
- Install Firefox from the AppCenter

  - [Netflix now supports Firefox on Linux](http://techblog.netflix.com/2017/03/update-on-html5-video-for-netflix.html)!
- [Install the chromium-widevine plugin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172364/netflix-works-on-chrome-but-not-chromium#172366)

  - Chromium-widevine may not work properly on elementary; see [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1371274).

Comment: Cool, thanks for the update! If this works for you, please mark the answer as "accepted" so that folks know that this problem has been resolved. Thank you!